# Unable to include a new file into my vb.net project without it being listed as miscellaneous [Visual Studio 2019]

Tags: vb.net, include, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to divide my Form1.vb file into multiple files. So I right clicked on the file > Add > Add New Item > Class. The class.vb file appears in the project folder, but when you open the file into the editor, it is listed as a miscellaneous file under the tab.

Is there a way or should I just continue with my enormous file?

I read somewhere that there should be an option to 'include in project' when you right click the file, but it won't appear when I right click it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat confusing here.

You can certainly add a class, and make sure the file extension is still .vb.

Since it is a class, then such code will be compiled by default.

But, you can right click on the file, and set the properties if not already set correctly.

So, say we wanted to move out some code to a new class, so with Form1, I can add a new class called Form1Stuff.vb.

So, now right click on that class, and you should see this:

[image]

From above, we select properties, and thus see this:

[image]

So, for above, you should see build action = Compile.

On the other hand, since you planning to "move" code out of a form, then I not all sure that creating a new class is a good approach. You could consider adding a code module, since in effect, any code you want to call/use in the class would require you having to create a instance of that class.

However, if you create and add a code module, then no such instance of the class need be created. Just keep in mind that if you do use a module in place of a class, then don't have global (public) members in that code module, since then you not be able to have multiple instances of that form in question.

And it not clear when you state:

> > when you open the file into the editor, it is listed as a miscellaneous file under the tab.

Hum, as my above screen shots show, that file if added using Visual Studio should see and know the file is a vb code file (class, or module).